# Heap Analytics for react native app

Tags: react-native, analytics, heap-analytics

Heap Analytics automatically tracks all events so you can analyze data in hindsight without having to manually define all events upfront.

Unfortunately, Heap does not seem to work in this way when used with a react native app. Does anybody know an analytics solution for React Native iOS, where all events are tracked automatically or how to get Heap working in that way without having to define all events manually?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question does not fit the StackOverflow's rules because it's too broad and will attract only opinion based answers (so expect it to be closed). Please, go to the: http://stackoverflow.com/help, then read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.